# I would like to know how to write Java bytecode that initializes static class variables

Tags: java, bytecode

I am studying Java byte code now.
I want to write Java bytecode to make Test.java in java source as below.
I want to declare and initialize static variables in a class.

Test.java

```
public class Test {
    public static int a=1;
    public Test() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] var0) {

    }
}
```

Command Result : javap -c Test

```
public class Test {
  public static int a;

  public Test();
    Code:
       0: aload_0
       1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
       4: return

  public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
    Code:
       0: return

  **static {};
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: putstatic     #2                  // Field a:I
       4: return**
}
```

Code I am writing

Test.j

```
.class public Test
.super java/lang/Object
.field public static a I
.method public <init>()V
    aload_0
    invokenonvirtual java/lang/Object/<init>()V
    return
.end method

.method public static main([Ljava/lang/String;)V
    .limit stack 32
    .limit locals 32
return
.end method
```

I use jasmin-2.4 to turn java bytecode into .class.
I want to know how to write java bytecode in static {};
    Code:
       0: iconst_1
       1: putstatic     #2                  // Field a:I
       4: return

Sorry for the strange English sentences.
Thank you if you let me know.

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: yong wants to know how to write Java bytecode in `static {}; ....`. Please don't ask what's the question, but for clarifications.

Answer (score 3):

For completeness, the behavior of initializers for static fields not being a compile-time constant is described as [Step 9 of the class initialization](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se13/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2-300-I) in the Java Language Specification:

> Next, execute either the class variable initializers and static initializers of the class, or the field initializers of the interface, in textual order, as though they were a single block.

This block is what `javap` prints as `static {}`, hiding the implementation detail you’re interested in.

For this detail, we have to refer to the Java Virtual Machine Specification , [§2.9.2., Class Initialization Methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9.2):

> A method is a *class or interface initialization method* if all of the following are true:
>
> - It has the special name `<clinit>`.
> - It is `void` ([§4.3.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.3.3)).
> - [...] the method has its `ACC_STATIC` flag set and takes no arguments  ([§4.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.6)).

I omitted details about which properties were not enforced in older JVMs, as you shouldn’t exploit those flaws. The class initializer should always have the properties specified above.

Generally, [the Java Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/index.html) is a document you should always have at hand when you are dealing with Java bytecode.